# Select All checkboxes of particular table without any table id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have 3 tables in a page and arranged as a Collapse and Expand functionality. So I want to implement "select ALL" functionality against the table, which the table rows contains checkbox. If I click "Select ALL", it should select that particular table checkboxes not other 2 tables checkboxes.

The problem here is that, these 3 tables doesn't contain table id and Select ALL" will be there in each of the table (thead). If I select "Select ALL" for the first table then it should select first table rows checkboxes and so on for the other 2 tables

So is there any way we can implement without table id and select dynamically table row checkboxes?

Appreciated for your answers.

Thanks.

Comment: Sample HTML? Where *is* this 'select ALL' checkbox? In, before or after the table? Somewhere else entirely?

Comment: "Select ALL" will be there in each of the table (thead). If I select "Select ALL" for the first table then it should select first table rows checkboxes and so on for the other 2 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the 'select all' checkbox has the class-name `'selectAll'`, and is located within the table itself:

```
$('input.selectAll').change(function(){
    var all = this;
    $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', all.checked);
});
```

```js
$('input.selectAll').change(function() {
  var all = this;
  $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', all.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" />Select All</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" />Select All</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" />Select All</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `eq()` to get the tables by index. Indexes starts from `0`

```
$('table').eq(0); // selects first table
$('table').eq(1); // selects second table and so on...
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to track for other 2 tables? I mean, which table it's clicking to check all the checkboxes?